# Please help me to random it without repeat element.

Tags: java, html, random

This below code it was run by repeat the same elements, 
what i want is to random it without repeat.

```
public class khmerAlphabetExercise extends Activity {

    AlphabetData data;
    MediaPlayer mp;
    int dataType;
    int dataKey;    
    Random random;
    private ImageView iv1, iv2, iv3,iv4;
    private ImageView[] imgs = { iv1, iv3, iv3,iv4 };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_khmer_exercise);       

        int[] imageViews={R.id.ex_con1,R.id.ex_con2,R.id.ex_con3,R.id.ex_con4};
        //int images[]={R.drawable.con_ex_01,R.drawable.con_ex_02,R.drawable.con_ex_03,R.drawable.con_ex_04,R.drawable.con_ex_05,R.drawable.con_ex_06,R.drawable.con_ex_07,R.drawable.con_ex_08,R.drawable.con_ex_09,R.drawable.con_ex_10};
        int[] images={data.getImageId()};
        random = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());

        for(int v : imageViews)     
        {
            ImageView iv = (ImageView)findViewById(v);
            iv.setImageResource(images[random.nextInt(images.length)]);                
        }   
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could keep a counter of the images left to select. And everytime you choose one you swap it in the original array with the last unselected.

So, for example, you have an array {0,1,2,3,4}. The Length of unselected will be 5, lets call it **l**

1. Choose a random number **n** between 0 an **l-1**
2. Your new element is the element at **n**.
3. Swap the element at **n** with the element at **l-1**, substract one to **l** and go back to point **1** if l bigger than 0. Go to point 4 **if l == 0**.
4. You finish

Comment: Thanks for your value help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Collections.shuffle

```
Collections.shuffle(Arrays.asList(images));
```

then you can just add this images one by one using a simple for loop without randomizing positions. BTW in your example images contains only one element..

Comment: Thanks for your value help